# Why doesn't this code simply print letters A to Z?

Tags: php

```
<?php
for ($i = 'a'; $i <= 'z'; $i++)
    echo "$i\n";
```

This snippet gives the following output (newlines are replaced by spaces):

> a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z aa ab ac ad ae af ag ah ai aj ak al am an ao ap aq ar as at au av aw ax ay az ba bb bc bd be bf bg bh bi bj bk bl bm bn bo bp bq br bs bt bu bv bw bx by bz ca cb cc cd ce cf cg ch ci cj ck cl cm cn co cp cq cr cs ct cu cv cw cx cy cz da db dc dd de df dg dh di dj dk dl dm dn do dp dq dr ds dt du dv dw dx dy dz ea eb ec ed ee ef eg eh ei ej ek el em en eo ep eq er es et eu ev ew ex... on to yz

Comment: PHP is not C, even if the syntax tries to convince you of the contrary.

Comment: This works for me with a very small change: for ($i = 'a'; $i != 'aa'; $i++) { echo "$i\n"; }

Comment: The comment about that PHP is not C - was the most keenest, example: in c: char c = 'a'; is not the same as in php: `$c = 'a';`, the point is that in C there is type of char(character 1 symbol), but not in PHP, if U tell PHP `$c = 'a';` - means this is a string with just 1 character. That's why U can't loop through 28 characters adequately in PHP.  I hope every programmer will learn low-level languages and strong-typing along with it, without forgetting about Math practices, which will help them to be stronger.

Comment: Wow that is really cool, But why it didnt stopped at "z"

Comment: For a way of getting the expected end-point by using equality (`==` or `!=`) [check out this answer to a related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18967283/157957).

Comment: If I were the parser, I would throw a fatal error when I see an expression like 'a'++

Comment: @zeusakm: A `char` is not a "character" or "symbol" (despite the illusion provided by char _literals_); it is an integer. That's really important.

Answer (score 342, accepted):

From the [docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's.
>
> For example, in Perl `'Z'+1` turns into `'AA'`, while in C `'Z'+1` turns into `'['` ( `ord('Z') == 90`, `ord('[') == 91` ).
>
> Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported.

**[From Comments:-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098345/why-doesnt-this-code-simply-print-letters-a-to-z?rq=1#comment4411983_4098397)**
It should also be noted that `<=` is a lexicographical comparison, so `'z'+1 ≤ 'z'`. (Since `'z'+1 = 'aa' ≤ 'z'`. But `'za' ≤ 'z'` is the first time the comparison is false.) Breaking when `$i == 'z'` would work, for instance.

[Example here](http://codepad.org/0LISfZjE).

Comment: Hah..that's crazy! I've always used `ord()` so I never noticed this.

Comment: For completeness, you should also add that "<=" is lexicographical comparison, so 'z'+1 ≤ 'z'. (Since 'z'+1='aa'≤'z'. But 'zz'≤'z' is the first time the comparison is false.) Breaking when $i=='z' would work, for instance.

Comment: as ShreevatsaR is saying, it's the comparator, not the arithmetic that's the trouble, don't focus on the ++ operator

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: actually, 'yz'+1 = 'za'. The first comparison that fails is 'za'<='z'

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! Yeah, the key point is that `'aa'` is [lexicographically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) smaller than `'z'`, that's why the loop continues. And it stops on `'yz'` because `'za'` is greater than `z`. Check [this example](http://codepad.org/0LISfZjE).

Comment: in PHP 'z'+1; is 1, not 'aa' but if $a='z'; $a++; then $a=='aa' http://codepad.org/SnjELFxD

Answer (score 124):

Because once 'z' is reached (and this is a valid result within your range, the $i++ increments it to the next value in sequence), the next value will be 'aa'; and alphabetically, 'aa' is < 'z', so the comparison is never met

```
for ($i = 'a'; $i != 'aa'; $i++) 
    echo "$i\n";
```

Comment: It is odd that 'z'++ = 'aa', but 'aa' < 'z'.  That logic doesn't flow very well.

Comment: @Matthew: Alphabetize them. 'aa' would come first, thus it's "less than" the string 'z'. The loop terminates at 'zz' because it's alphabetically "greater than" (comes after) 'z'. It's illogical in the sense that you can "increment" something and get a lesser value, but it's logical in an alphabetical sense.

Comment: The character incrementor is Perl logic (see CMS's quote from the docs). The comparison 'aa' < 'z' is standard string comparison logic. Not odd, once you understand how to use it... from the answers here, a lot of people don't.

Comment: @eldarerathis Oh I definitely understand how it is working.  I just find it odd at the same time.

Comment: @Matthew: Ah, gotcha. Misinterpreted your comment a bit.

Comment: It's incredibly useful for me, playing around with Excel columns that follow the same logical series

Comment: @Artefacto - well I don't ever use the <= or >= operators in that structure, because I consider them purely arithmetic operators. I really wish decrementing was supported as well, it would be incredibly useful, and supporting non-English languages would make for some very interesting logic. I'd love to see the minds of the core PHP development team spontaneously explode if anybody suggested that it should :)

Comment: @Mark Excel comes to mind first for me as well. I wonder if there's *any* other case where this could possibly be useful?

Comment: @Matthew Vines: I cant upvote your comment enough. Yes i so agree.

Comment: @dbkk - The game of "Battleships" uses a grid with alpha references for the columns, so there's another example

Comment: @acidzombie24 - it will stop at 'za' because 'za' > 'z', which is why 'yz' is the last printed value in the OP's output

Comment: @acidzombie24: I actually meant 'za' as Mark Baker pointed out. That was a typo I didn't notice >.>

Answer (score 97):

Others answers explain the observed behavior of the posted code.  Here is one way to do what you want (and it's cleaner code, IMO):

```
foreach (range('a', 'z') as $i)
    echo "$i\n";
```

In response to ShreevatsaR's comment/question about the [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function:  Yes, it produces the "right endpoint", i.e. the values passed to the function are in the range.  To illustrate, the output from the above code was:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

Comment: Does range() include the right endpoint? From experience with other languages, that's unexpected too!

Comment: @ShreevatsaR:  Yes, range() gives the "right" endpoint, see my edited answer (and follow the link to the function) for more info.

Comment: What can I say… more PHP madness. :-) There's no other language I know of in which range() works this way. (Certainly not, say, Haskell or Python.) Didn't Dijkstra write something about this?

Comment: Madness is in the inconsistency of PHP. range('A','CZ') works totally differently to the ++ incrementor, and the resulting array will just contain three values: A, B and C.

Answer (score 35):

Others already said why PHP doesn't show what you expect. Here's how you get the result you might want:

```
<?php
for ($i = ord('a'); $i <= ord('z'); $i++)
    echo chr($i);
?>
```

Comment: Unnecessary. you don't need to do the ord() at all, just the correct comparison to terminate the loop

Comment: +1 Much more comprehensible when not familiar with one of the more eccentric features of PHP.

Comment: This is an excellent example of self-documenting code. It is easily comprehensible precisely b/c it uses  ordinal values and then displays the variable as a character.  The for-loop would be more efficient if the test for the maximum value is determined only once as follows: "for ($i = ord('a'),$max = ord('z'); $i <= $max; $i++){"

Answer (score 22):

Why not just use `range('a','z')`?

Answer (score 4):

Try this code. I think this code will be helpful to you.

```
$alphas = range('A', 'Z');
foreach($alphas as $value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

Display 26 letters in sequence.

Answer (score 3):

PHP has the function of looping letters and can exceed beyond single characters; the rest will be done this way: aa ab ac... zz, and so on.

#### Try this:

```
<?php
for ($i = 'a'; $i !== 'aa'; $i++)
    echo "$i\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php

$i = 'a';
do {
echo ($j=$i++),"\r\n";
} while (ord($j) < ord($i));

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Also this can be used:

```
for ($i = 'a'; $i <= 'z'; $i=chr(ord($i)+1))
    echo "$i\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

While the above answers are insightful to what's going on, and pretty interesting (I didn't know it would behave like this, and its good to see why.

The easiest fix (although perhaps not the most meaningful) would be just to change the condition to $i != 'z'

```
<?php
for ($i = 'a'; $i != 'z'; $i++)  
    echo "$i\n";
?>
```

Comment: Note that this will only give you a to y, not z

Comment: doh! yep, good point.  I can see the logic behind both the increment and the comparison, but it sure is strange that sometimes $a++ < $a

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this code will work. It’s easy & can be understood:

```
<?php
$ascii_val = ord("a");
for($i=$ascii_val;$i<$ascii_val+26;$i++){
echo chr($i)."\n";
}
?>
```

where 26 is the total number of letters in the alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP does not consider 'AA' less than 'Z'.
The best way to make this is:

```
for($i = 'a'; $i != 'aa'; $i++) {
  echo $i;
}
```

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

Answer (score 0):

**There are several ways to do that.**

**1.** First you can take the range from 'a' to 'z'. Then iterate a loop over it.

```
foreach(range('a', 'z') as $i)
{
    echo $i . "\n";
}
```

**2.** You can print the letters using asci value of the characters.

```
for($i = 97 ; $i<=122; $i++)
{
  echo chr($i) . "\n";
}
```

**3.** You can take the asci value of 'a' and run a loop till the asci value of 'z':

```
for ($x = ord('a'); $x <= ord('z'); $x++)
{
    echo chr($x) . "\n";
}
```

**4.** For printing a new line in html you can append the 
to the end of each characters.

```
for($i='a';$i<='z';$i++)
{
    echo $i. "<br />"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way to get the display of characters a-z:

```
<?php
 for ($i = 'a'; $i < 'z'; $i++){
     echo "$i\n";
 }
 echo $i;  // 'z'
```

See [live code](https://3v4l.org/RQfEm)
Once the conditional loop becomes false, $i will have already been incremented and have the string value corresponding to 'z' which can be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

this code will work. It’s easy & can be understood:

```
<?php


// print form A to ZZ  like this
// A B C ... AA AB AC ... ZA .. ZZ
$pre = "";
$i = ord('a');
for ($x = ord('a'); $pre . strtoupper(chr($x-1)) != 'AH'; $x++)
{
    echo "". $pre . strtoupper(chr($x)) . "\n";

    if(chr($x) === "z"){
        $pre = strtoupper(chr($i++));
        $x = ord('a');
        $x--;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Wow I really didn't know about this but its not a big code you can try echo "z" after loop Mark is Absolutely Right I use his method but if you want alternative then this may also you can try

```
<?php
for ($i = "a"; $i = "y"; $i++) {
    echo "$i\n";
    if ($i == "z") {}
}
echo "z";
?>
```