# PHP Character Iteration In For Loop Issue

Tags: php, for-loop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why doesn’t this code simply print letters A to Z?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098345/why-doesnt-this-code-simply-print-letters-a-to-z)

Why is that when I use the following loop structure, I get the proper result -

```
for ($c = "A"; $c <= "Y"; $c++)
{
    echo $c.", ";
}
```

The result I get is -

> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y,

Which seems allright. But when I replace `Y` with `Z` in the above for loop I get unusual results

```
for ($c = "A"; $c <= "Z"; $c++)
{
    echo $c.", ";
}
```

And the result I get is -

> A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z, AA, AB, AC, AD, AE, AF, AG, AH, AI, AJ, AK, AL, AM, AN, AO, AP, AQ, AR, AS, AT, AU, AV, AW, AX, AY, AZ, BA, BB, BC, BD, BE, BF, BG, BH, BI, BJ, BK, BL, BM, BN, BO, BP, BQ, BR, BS, BT, BU, BV, BW, BX, BY, BZ, CA, CB, CC, CD, CE, CF, CG, CH, CI, CJ, CK, CL, CM, CN, CO, CP, CQ, CR, CS, CT, CU, CV, CW, CX, CY, CZ, DA, DB, DC, DD, DE, DF, DG, DH, DI, DJ, DK, DL, DM, DN, DO, DP, DQ, DR, DS, DT, DU, DV, DW, DX, DY, DZ, EA, EB, EC, ED, EE, EF, EG, EH, EI, EJ, EK, EL, EM, EN, EO, EP, EQ, ER, ES, ET, EU, EV, EW, EX, EY, EZ, FA, FB, FC, FD, FE, FF, FG, FH, FI, FJ, FK, FL, FM, FN, FO, FP, FQ, FR, FS, FT, FU, FV, FW, FX, FY, FZ, GA, GB, GC, GD, GE, GF, GG, GH, GI, GJ, GK, GL, GM, GN, GO, GP, GQ, GR, GS, GT, GU, GV, GW, GX, GY, GZ, HA, HB, HC, HD, HE, HF, HG, HH, HI, HJ, HK, HL, HM, HN, HO, HP, HQ, HR, HS, HT, HU, HV, HW, HX, HY, HZ, IA, IB, IC, ID, IE, IF, IG, IH, II, IJ, IK, IL, IM, IN, IO, IP, IQ, IR, IS, IT, IU, IV, IW, IX, IY, IZ, JA, JB, JC, JD, JE, JF, JG, JH, JI, JJ, JK, JL, JM, JN, JO, JP, JQ, JR, JS, JT, JU, JV, JW, JX, JY, JZ, KA, KB, KC, KD, KE, KF, KG, KH, KI, KJ, KK, KL, KM, KN, KO, KP, KQ, KR, KS, KT, KU, KV, KW, KX, KY, KZ, LA, LB, LC, LD, LE, LF, LG, LH, LI, LJ, LK, LL, LM, LN, LO, LP, LQ, LR, LS, LT, LU, LV, LW, LX, LY, LZ, MA, MB, MC, MD, ME, MF, MG, MH, MI, MJ, MK, ML, MM, MN, MO, MP, MQ, MR, MS, MT, MU, MV, MW, MX, MY, MZ, NA, NB, NC, ND, NE, NF, NG, NH, NI, NJ, NK, NL, NM, NN, NO, NP, NQ, NR, NS, NT, NU, NV, NW, NX, NY, NZ, OA, OB, OC, OD, OE, OF, OG, OH, OI, OJ, OK, OL, OM, ON, OO, OP, OQ, OR, OS, OT, OU, OV, OW, OX, OY, OZ, PA, PB, PC, PD, PE, PF, PG, PH, PI, PJ, PK, PL, PM, PN, PO, PP, PQ, PR, PS, PT, PU, PV, PW, PX, PY, PZ, QA, QB, QC, QD, QE, QF, QG, QH, QI, QJ, QK, QL, QM, QN, QO, QP, QQ, QR, QS, QT, QU, QV, QW, QX, QY, QZ, RA, RB, RC, RD, RE, RF, RG, RH, RI, RJ, RK, RL, RM, RN, RO, RP, RQ, RR, RS, RT, RU, RV, RW, RX, RY, RZ, SA, SB, SC, SD, SE, SF, SG, SH, SI, SJ, SK, SL, SM, SN, SO, SP, SQ, SR, SS, ST, SU, SV, SW, SX, SY, SZ, TA, TB, TC, TD, TE, TF, TG, TH, TI, TJ, TK, TL, TM, TN, TO, TP, TQ, TR, TS, TT, TU, TV, TW, TX, TY, TZ, UA, UB, UC, UD, UE, UF, UG, UH, UI, UJ, UK, UL, UM, UN, UO, UP, UQ, UR, US, UT, UU, UV, UW, UX, UY, UZ, VA, VB, VC, VD, VE, VF, VG, VH, VI, VJ, VK, VL, VM, VN, VO, VP, VQ, VR, VS, VT, VU, VV, VW, VX, VY, VZ, WA, WB, WC, WD, WE, WF, WG, WH, WI, WJ, WK, WL, WM, WN, WO, WP, WQ, WR, WS, WT, WU, WV, WW, WX, WY, WZ, XA, XB, XC, XD, XE, XF, XG, XH, XI, XJ, XK, XL, XM, XN, XO, XP, XQ, XR, XS, XT, XU, XV, XW, XX, XY, XZ, YA, YB, YC, YD, YE, YF, YG, YH, YI, YJ, YK, YL, YM, YN, YO, YP, YQ, YR, YS, YT, YU, YV, YW, YX, YY, YZ,

Any reason for this kind of behaviour?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Straight from the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php):

> PHP follows Perl's convention when dealing with arithmetic operations on character variables and not C's. For example, in PHP and Perl $a = 'Z'; $a++; turns $a into 'AA', while in C a = 'Z'; a++; turns a into '[' (ASCII value of 'Z' is 90, ASCII value of '[' is 91). Note that character variables can be incremented but not decremented and even so only plain ASCII characters (a-z and A-Z) are supported. Incrementing/decrementing other character variables has no effect, the original string is unchanged.

The reason it keeps going is because you're attempting a numerical comparison (`<=` and `AA < Z`, `ZA == Z` (when doing `<=`)) instead of a literal value comparison (`==`).

In light of this, you could use the following code:

```
for ($c = "A"; $c != "Z"; $c++)
{
    echo $c . ", ";
}
```

.. or use the actual ordinal value of the characters (which is the better solution in my opinion):

```
for ($c = ord("A"); $c <= ord("Z"); $c++)
{
    echo chr($c) . ", ";
}
```

Comment: Good solution but it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Don't use < or > (or >= or <=) for comparisons when incrementing characters, use !==

```
for ($c = "A"; $c !== "AA"; $c++)
{
    echo $c.", ";
}
```

where the 'AA' is "one higher than" the endpoint you want

```
$lastCharacter = 'Z';
$lastCharacter++;
for ($c = "A"; $c !== $lastCharacter; $c++)
{
    echo $c.", ";
}
```

All words comprised of ASCII characters (the range A-Z) will be <= 'Z' until you get to ZA, because the compasrison is a string comparison, and "AA" is < "Z" if the strings are sorted. See my answer to a [previous version of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098345/why-doesnt-this-code-simply-print-letters-a-to-z/4098414#4098414)

Comment: This is also one of many solutions, but it still doesn't answer **Why is that happening?**

Answer (score 1):

Congrats, you found one of the many inconsistencies in PHP. In short: the + and < operators work totally different on strings.

- increasing a single-letter string works as you would expect
- increasing `Z` results in `AA` and so on (think about Excel columns)
- comparing single-letter strings works as you would expect
- comparing multiple-letter strings works lexicographically (letter by letter)

Now the interesting edge case is:

```
'Z' <= 'Z'    // because equal
'Z'++ == 'AA' // because magic
'AA' <= 'Z'   // because A comes before Z
```

Comment: This is what I found out when checking the `ord` outputs.