# php Algorithm to print a aa aaa ab aab till zzz

Tags: php, loops

Hi i need To print from a to zzz upto 3 letters , for example my output should be

```
A
B
.
.
.
Z
AA
AB
.
.
AZ
BA
BB
.
.
.
ZZ
AAA
AAB
.
.
.
.
ZZZ
```

I was trying hard for past 5 hours , I cant find any logic and i tried below code

```
<?php
for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) { 
for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {     
for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {     
    echo chr($i).chr($i).chr($i)."<br>";      
}
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

PHP has a convenient feature where incrementing a string works exactly as you describe.

So all you need is:

```
for( $i="A"; $i!="ZZZ"; $i++) {
    echo $i."<br />";
}
```

EDIT: revised solution that prints 'ZZZ' (instead of 'ZZY') last:

```
$i = 'A';
do {
  echo $i . '<br />';
} while ( $i++ != 'ZZZ' );
```

Comment: great solution, but watch that off by 1 error! `$i!="AAAA"` for the condition will do it

Comment: Worth noting that this ends on "ZZY". Otherwise, great solution.

Comment: I took the liberty to submit an alternate solution that ends with the desired string and doesn't force you to think what the next one is.

Comment: @finishingmove I took the liberty of editing your edit, as I realised it looked reminiscent of a `do ... while` loop. The key is to realise that `if ( $i ) { } $i++` is the same as `if ( $i++ )` (post-increment "returns" the original value, not the new one) which makes the test the last thing in the loop.

Comment: Incidentally, the "Related Questions" box pointed me to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4098345/157957) which explains why using a comparison other than equality (`<`, `<=`, etc) to break out of the loop won't work, even though it seems like the logical thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you have it working perfectly yet but your code needed a very minor tweak:

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/zqh-dyv