# Loop through range A to AAZ

Tags: php, foreach

How I can loop through A to AAZ in php.
I can loop through A to Z and list them down by using the below code

```
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}
```

Is there a way by which I can loop through A to AAZ.
So the output should be

`A,B,C,..Z,AA,AB,AC,AD...AZ,BA,BB,BC...AAZ.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't this code simply print letters A to Z?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098345/why-doesnt-this-code-simply-print-letters-a-to-z)

Answer (score 0):

You have to create multiple loops for that:

```
// Write A...Z
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char) {
    echo $char . "\n";
}

// Write AA...ZZ
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char1) {
    foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char2) {
        echo $char1 . $char2 . "\n";
    }
}

// Write AAA...ZZZ
foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char1) {
    foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char2) {
        foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char3) {
            echo $char1 . $char2 . $char3 . "\n";
        }
    }
}
```